# Does the Holm-Bonferroni procedure really correct for FWER in the context of ANOVA?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I wanted to make sure that post-hoc tests with the Holm-Bonferroni procedure behave nominally on typical ANOVA data under the null hypothesis.

To do so, I computed the p-values and FWER obtained from running Holm-Bonferroni corrected pairwise tests on N = 100,000 toy datasets.

```
set.seed(1)
N = 100000        # number of experiments
K = 4             # number of levels
C = K*(K-1)/2     # number of comparisons

pvals = t(sapply(1:N, function(i) 
                 pairwise.t.test(x = rnorm(K*100) , g = rep(1:K,each = 100) , 
                 p.adjust.method = 'holm')[3]$p.value))
pvals = pvals[,!is.na(pvals[1,])]
```

I extract the FWER and the number of type-I errors per experiment:

```
mean(rowSums(pvals < 0.05) > 0)     
hist(rowSums(pvals < 0.05) , breaks = -0.5:5.5)$counts
```

which yields:

```
0.0412
95882  3145   801   161    11     0
```

The FWER is clearly below 0.05 and we see there are experiments with many type-I errors, even though the overall type-I error rate over all experiments is 0.0527. I suspect this is due to the correlation between the C tests because I checked the FWER would be nominal in case of independence (*).

If so, then why is the recommendation to use the Holm-Bonferroni correction for post-hoc tests ubiquitous?

(*) if the C tests were independent, the HB procedure WOULD correct for FWER:

```
pvals_ind = matrix(runif(C*N)*C , ncol = C)
mean(rowSums(pvals_ind < 0.05) > 0)
hist(rowSums(pvals_ind < 0.05) , breaks = -0.5:5.5)$counts
```

which yields:

```
0.0497
95026  4869   104     1     0     0
```

Comment: Indeed, it does not seem legitimate to use the HB procedure when we do all the possible comparisons, because they're not independent. Therefore HB should only be used when carrying planned comparisons (and not post hoc as is often claimed). The planned comparisons still need be orthogonal.

https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/bwebb/statistics/Planned-comparison_post-hoc.pdf

Comment: Holm-Bonferroni is the closure of the Bonferroni correction, therefore it makes no assumptions on the dependency of the test-statistics. As you can see, when the data is dependent then the FWER is below the expected threshold (If you'll have a lot of true differences it will also be lower). As long as you specify the number of tests conducted in advance (not after viewing the data) the procedure is valid and can be used as a post-hoc test.

Comment: Your first two sentences seem contradictory to me. From my simulations, the procedure seems to fail to control the FWER in case of dependence.

Comment: Controlling the FWER implies that the FWER is below or equal to specified probability, not that it is should equal it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate.